# Class members garbled after copy-construction or copy by assignment (sometimes)

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rule-of-three, copy-assignment

My class `NRRanNormal` represents a normally-distributed random variable.  By default, instances are normally distributed with mean 0 and stdev 1 (i.e., a standard normal random variable).

*Sometimes* when I copy `NRRanNormal` objects, the mean and stdev of the object copied into (or constructed via the copy constructor) are garbled and nonsense. I'm having a hard time finding the cause of this garbling.

For testing purposes, the following function displays the mean and stdev of a given `NRRanNormal` object:

```
void go(NRRanNormal& rv, const string label) {
    std::cout << label     << "\n"
              << "Mean:  " << rv.getMean()  << "\n"
              << "Stdev: " << rv.getStdev() << "\n\n";
}
```

Now, let's see what happens in the following 4 cases:

```
NRRanNormal foo;
go(foo, "foo");

NRRanNormal bar1 = foo;
go(bar1, "bar1");

NRRanNormal bar2;
bar2 = foo;
go(bar2, "bar2");

NRRanNormal bar3(foo);
go(bar3, "bar3");
```

The output of the above statements is the following:

```
foo
Mean:  0
Stdev: 1

bar1
Mean:  5.55633e-317
Stdev: 6.95332e-310

bar2
Mean:  0
Stdev: 1

bar3
Mean:  0
Stdev: 0
```

As you can see, simply instantiating an object (`foo`) works as expected.

Now, when I do `NRRanNormal  bar1 = foo;`, the object `bar1` is garbled.  However, when I do `NRRanNormal bar2; bar2 = foo;`, the object `bar2` is **not** garbled.  This puzzles me.  I thought that a statement block such as

```
MyClass A;
MyClass B = A;
```

is actually converted by the compiler to the statement block

```
MyClass A;
MyClass B;
B = A;
```

Therefore, unless what I just wrote immediately above is incorrect, it seems that `bar1` and `bar2` should have *exactly* the same member values.  But as you can see from the output pasted above, `bar1` is garbled whereas `bar2` is fine.

**How can this be?**

You'll also notice that `bar3` is garbled.  I'm not sure whether this is the same problem, or another problem.

---

Here is a simplified version of the interface and implementation of `NRRanNormal`:

```
class NRRanNormal {
public:

    NRRanNormal();

    ~NRRanNormal();

    NRRanNormal(const NRRanNormal& nrran);

    NRRanNormal& operator= (const NRRanNormal& nrran);

    double getMean()  const;    
    double getStdev() const;    
    long   getSeed()  const;

private:    
    double m_mean, m_stdev;     
    long m_seed;    
    Normaldev* stream; // underlying C struct RN generator

};

NRRanNormal::NRRanNormal() { // by default, N(0,1)
    m_mean  = 0.0;
    m_stdev = 1.0;
    m_seed  = 12345L;
    stream  = new Normaldev(m_mean, m_stdev, m_seed);
}

NRRanNormal::~NRRanNormal() { delete stream; }

NRRanNormal::NRRanNormal(const NRRanNormal& nrran) {
    stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());
    *stream = *(nrran.stream);
}

NRRanNormal& NRRanNormal::operator= (const NRRanNormal& nrran) {            
    if(this == &nrran)
        return *this;

    delete stream;
    stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());
    *stream = *(nrran.stream);

    return *this;
}

double NRRanNormal::getMean()  const { return m_mean; }    
double NRRanNormal::getStdev() const { return m_stdev; }    
long   NRRanNormal::getSeed()  const { return m_seed; }
```

The `Normaldev` struct is from Numerical Recipes 3d Edition.

**Is there something wrong with my copy-assignment operator or copy constructor?**

---

Here is `Normaldev`, stripped of the proprietary calculations.

```
typedef double Doub;        
typedef unsigned long long int Ullong;
typedef unsigned int Uint;

struct Ranq1 {
    Ullong v;
    Ranq1(Ullong j) : v(/* some long number here */) {
        /* proprietary calculations here */
    }
    inline Ullong int64() {
        /* proprietary calculations here */
    }
    inline Doub doub() { /* proprietary calculations here */ }
    inline Uint int32() { return (Uint)int64(); }
};

struct Normaldev : Ranq1 {
    Doub mu,sig;
    Normaldev(Doub mmu, Doub ssig, Ullong i):
    Ranq1(i), mu(mmu), sig(ssig){}
    Doub dev() {
        /* proprietary calculations here */
    }
};
```

Comment: As a side note, your assignment operator is not exception safe: if `new` throws you'll end up deleting `stream` several times. You might want to `new` first (using a temporary pointer) and `delete` only if it succeeded. But do you *really* need to dynamically allocate `stream`? At the very least use a smart pointer to help with exception safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem

```
NRRanNormal::NRRanNormal(const NRRanNormal& nrran) {
    stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());
    *stream = *(nrran.stream);
}
```

should be

```
NRRanNormal::NRRanNormal(const NRRanNormal& nrran) : 
    m_mean(nrran.m_mean), 
    m_stdev(nrran.m_stdev), 
    m_seed(nrran.m_seed)
{
    stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());
    *stream = *(nrran.stream);
}
```

Your copy constructor fails to copy the mean, stddev and seed. Your assignment operator has the same problem it should be

```
NRRanNormal& NRRanNormal::operator= (const NRRanNormal& nrran) {            
    if(this == &nrran)
        return *this;

    m_mean  = nrran.m_mean;
    m_stdev = nrran.m_stdev;
    m_seed  = nrran.m_seed;
    delete stream;
    stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());
    *stream = *(nrran.stream);

    return *this;
}
```

I guess you were focussed so much on the tricky pointer in your class you forgot about the basic stuff.

BTW the code

```
MyClass A;
MyClass B = A;
```

is actually converted by the compiler to

```
MyClass A;
MyClass B(A);
```

in other words `MyClass B = A;` invokes the copy constructor (assuming A and B are the same type).

Comment: Goodness, me!  You're right, of course, it's the basic stuff that got me here.  Thanks a lot.  Also, good to know about the compiler conversion note.

Comment: And, in your corrected version, it might make sense to change `stream = new Normaldev(nrran.getMean(),nrran.getStdev(),nrran.getSeed());` to `stream = new Normaldev(m_mean,m_stdev,m_seed);`.  No big deal though.